# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields - Random Query Repeater by SubField value

Tags: php, loops, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to fetch **ONE** *random* row of testimonials, however that row must contain a "true" value for **sitewide_display** subfield.

I can't for the life of me get this to work, this just gives me whatever result it feels like upon refresh.

Is there some sort of conflict with using the conditional for the sub-field value (sitewide_display) within the while loop like this?

```
<?php $rows = get_field('testimonials' ); // get all the rows ?>
    <?php if( $rows ) : // if there are rows, continue ?>  
         <?php while( has_sub_field('testimonials') ) : ?>   
            <?php if( get_sub_field('sitewide_display')): ?> 
                <?php $rand_row = $rows[ array_rand( $rows ) ]; // get the first row ?>
                <?php  $rand_row_testimonial_name = $rand_row['testimonial_name' ]; // get the sub field value  ?>
                <?php echo $rand_row_testimonial_name; ?>            
            <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue with the following, if there is a more efficient way go ahead and comment!

```
<?php

$lists = get_field( 'testimonials' );
shuffle($lists);
if( $lists ){

    $i=0;
    foreach( $lists as $list ){
        if( $list['site-wide_display'] &&  $i < 1){
            echo $list['testimonial_name'];
            $i +=1;
        }


    }
}


?>
```