# ACF repeater sub-fields Shuffle (wordpress advance custom field)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I know how to shuffle repeaters every time the page loads by adding this code in function.php:

```
// Function to randomize Advanced Custome Fields' Repeaters
function my_acf_load_value3( $value, $post_id, $field )
{
    shuffle($value);
    return $value;
}

// Randomize ACF Clients' Repeater
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=reapter-name', 'my_acf_load_value3', 10, 3);
```

Take note that the code above is working fine and it randomizing the repeater,But my problem is I dont know how to shuffle the SUB FIELDS inside repeater, any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: can you explain your question little more what mean by shuffle ? Do you want to randomize sub-fields ?

this may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011261/wordpress-advanced-custom-fields-random-query-repeater-by-subfield-value

Comment: yes exactly, I want to randomize the SUBFIELDS. By using the function above it can shuffle/randomize the repeater but not the subfield.

Comment: print_r $value what is showing ?

Comment: this might help you.

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/randomizingshuffling-repeater-with-advanced-loop/

Comment: Yes thanks, but actually I got the code above in that link you gave, and its working fine, it randomizing the repeater BUT not the sub fields of the repeater, what I want is to randomize the sub-fields too. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you check out the advanced examples, you might be able to figure something out - : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/#examples

Comment: try this code .

$repeater = get_field( 'repeater_field_name' );
$rand = rand(0, (count($repeater) - 1));
echo $repeater[$rand]['sub_field_1'];

Answer (score 0):

You may shuffle the sub fields values by orderby(parameter) where you are calling it.
I am adding my custom code below

'post',

    'posts_per_page' => -1, 

    'meta_key' => 'project', 

    'orderby' => 'rand',

    'meta_compare' => 'EXISTS'      );


$query = new WP_Query($args);


while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();

if (have_rows('project')) {

  while(have_rows('project')) {

  the_row();

  ?>

">">

hope it helps